# Linear applications and invariance

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question in regard of this statement: "be $f \in \text{End}(V)$. A subspace of $V$ of dimension one is $f-$invariant iff it is generated by an eigenvector of $f$".

I have to say if this is true or not.

Well I think it is. What I understood from the theory is: having a linear transformation $f$ (in this case $f: V \to V$) and a vector $v \in V$, the smallest subspace $f-$invariat contains $v$ for sure and being it $f-$ invariant it must contain all the images of $v$ that is, $f(v)$, $f(v^2)$ and so on.

I also understood that $W$ is said to be $f-$invariant (where $f$ is an endomorphism of $V$) if $f$ transforms vectors of $W$ into vectors of $W$, where $W$ is a subspace of $W$, but in the question there is no mention of subspaces.

Anyway, if $A$ is the matrix that represents $f$, then by writing $f_A(x) = Ax$ I can say that studying the subspaces $A$-invariant of dimension one means to study the eigenvectors of $A$

- Why this? It's a bit unclear to me

Now, the subspaces $A-$invariant of dimension one are the ones and only those ones generated by exactly an eigenvector of $A$ (nonzero).

I think I am a bit confused maybe on this topics, and if you would help me it would be great.

Also I was thinking: what if the dimension is more than one? Does this generalize to higher dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;W:=Span\{v\}\;$ be a subspace of dimension one of $\;V\;$ which is $\;f\,-$ invariant. This means that

$$fv=kv\,,\,\,k\;\text{ a scalar}$$

since it must be $\;fv\in W\;$ again, and the above means $\;v\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;f\;$ (because it is clearly non zer0. Why?) with correspndent eigenvalue $\;k\;$ .

The other direction is even easier. Try it now. No need to go to representing matrices and etc.

Comment: This was clear thanks. So can this be generalised if the dimension is not $1$? Mi intuition goes with yes...

Comment: I mean, would there be some problem if the dimension of the subspace were $> 1$?

Comment: @Numb3rs  I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "generalized to dimension >1"... Any subspace generated by lin. ind. eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues is invariant, for example.